# Suspend `withTimeout`

Tags: kotlin, timer, kotlin-coroutines

My app starts from executing coroutine:

```
model.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val timeout = withTimeoutOrNull(TIMEOUT) {
            //send some initialization server requests
            true   //timeout=true
    }
    if (timeout!=null){
        // app started ok
    } else {
        // app freezed on start
    }
}
```

The problem is one of the initialization step - obtain user consent to share his personal data(GDPR) Consent form is a modal popup that waits for user input.But the timer is ticking all this time. Therefore after gdpr user may see `app starts too long` error.

Is there way to suspend `withTimeoutOrNull` timer and resume it after some time?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you wish to run this `Coroutine` only after the user has given the consent?

Comment: Then the first thing user sees in the app will be gdpr consent.Bad user expirience. 
I think there have to be 2 coroutines: before and after consent. I hoped there may be simpler workaround.

Comment: You can rest assured there's no way to pause the timer. The implementation schedules a cancellation task with the delay you give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported out of the box, but you can write your own version of `withTimeoutOrNull` that would support a pauseable timer. The key idea is to run your block in a separate `coroutineScope { ... }` and to `launch` a secondary helper coroutine that would cancel this scope after timeout. Now if you keep a reference to this helper `cancellationJob`, then you can cancel it when you need to pause your time and restart it when you need to resume timer.

That would give you essentially the same behavior that basic `withTimeout` has but with an added pauseability. A bit of extra code is needed to implement a `withTimeoutOrNull` variant. You'll need to catch your cancellation exception and replace it with null result.

A worked-out implementation can be found in this gist: https://gist.github.com/elizarov/c5b0fde43ca14efbb8bcab13ad43c6ca

Comment: Hey Roman it perfectly fits! I just replaced `withTimeoutOrNull`->`pauseableWithTimeoutOrNull`.BTW:It's not the best idea to rely on a clock.User may transfer it

Comment: could you explain what this parameter does?`block: suspend TimerScope.() -> T`. I guess it's a body of the main coroutine.A lambda.Then what is TimerScope?I can see `this`=`TimerScopeImpl` within this lambda.How can it be possible?I thought lambdas don't have their scope and inherit parent's one.

Comment: found! Its `receiver type`